# Get object that calls the function

Tags: javascript, html

I got a question regarding calling a function with HTML and getting this object back. Let me clarify my question with some code.

First i got this Javascript:

```
function Example() {
    var x_val = arguments[0];
    var y_val = arguments[1];
    var z_val = arguments[2];    
    console.log(x_val,y_val,z_val);
}
```

I call this Javascript by the following HTML:

```
<a id="test" href="#" onmouseover="Example(100,200,400)">test</a>
<a id="test2" href="#" onmouseover="Example(400,600,700)">test</a>
<a id="test3" href="#" onmouseover="Example(400,500,900)">test</a>
```

What I want is when I call the function i want to know which object has called the function and return the whole object.

So if I call the Example() function with the following hyperlink:

```
<a id="test2" href="#" onmouseover="Example(400,600,700)">test</a>
```

I want to get the following result:

```
outerHTML: <a id="test2" href="#" onmouseover="Example(400,600,700)">test</a>
```

Is that possible? (JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kny5jj8h/)

Comment: make it as fiddle for better approach?

Comment: pass `this` to the function `onmouseover="Example(this,100,200,400)"`

Comment: Why are you using jquery if you're not using jquery?

Comment: No in the JSFiddle that is wrong. I just forget to turn it off. I do not use jQuery, but could be a possibility in case it makes my life easier.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer to include plain JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing 'this' as an argument does not work in every situation.
use window.event to get the target of the event. In some older browsers event.target is not defined, in which case event.srcElement usually is.

```
function Example() {
    var target = window.event.target || window.event.srcElement;
    alert(target.id);

    var x_val = arguments[0];
    var y_val = arguments[1];
    var z_val = arguments[2];    
    console.log(x_val,y_val,z_val);
}
```

Comment: In Firefox you have to make the event handler accept the event object. Your current use of `event || window.event` is useless and equivalent to just `window.event`. It becomes only useful if `event` is a parameter.

Comment: Agreed, i copied this from one of my functions that accepts event as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Simply send a this parameter to the function and output the outerHtml:

```
<a id="test" href="#" onmouseover="Example(this,100,200,400)">test</a>


function Example(elem) {
    var x_val = arguments[1];
    var y_val = arguments[2];
    var z_val = arguments[3];    
    console.log(x_val,y_val,z_val);
    return elem.outerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Yep. As I said. Except arguments[0] is elem

Comment: Is it also possible to do this without adding this to the function call?

Comment: Yes. You can use the event.target instead but I prefer using this as an input param.

Answer (score 2):

Pass `this` as in

```
<a id="test" href="#" onmouseover="Example(this,100,200,400)">test</a>

function Example() {
    var elem = arguments[0];
    var x_val = arguments[1];
    var y_val = arguments[2];
    var z_val = arguments[3];    
    console.log(x_val,y_val,z_val,elem.outerHTML);
}
```

A better method would be to do

```
<a id="test" class="coordtest" href="#" data-coord="100,200,400">test</a>
```

and in the head do

```
window.onload=function() {
  var coordlinks = document.querySelectorAll(".coordtest");
  for (var i=0;i<coordlinks.length;i++) {
    coordlinks[i].onmouseover=function(e) {
      var coords = this.getAttribute("data-coord").split(",");
      var x_val = coords[0];
      var y_val = coords[1];
      var z_val = coords[2];
      console.log(this,x_val,y_val,z_val);
    }
  }
}
```

or in jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $(".coordtest").on("mouseover",function(e) {
    var coords = $(this).data("coord").split(",");
    var x_val = coords[0];
    var y_val = coords[1];
    var z_val = coords[2];
    console.log($(this),x_val,y_val,z_val);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `this` explicitly, as in `Example( this, 100, 200,300 )`, but it will change the number of arguments passed and you'd need to modify the function which may not always be the best idea (for example other parts of the application call the same function and rely on the current order of arguments).

You can also pass a reference to the node using `.call`:

```
<span onmouseover="Example.call(this, 10,20,30)">span</span>
```

This way the arguments are passed just like before, but `this` is bound to the span element:

```
function Example() {
    var x_val = arguments[0];
    var y_val = arguments[1];
    var z_val = arguments[2];    
    console.log(this, x_val,y_val,z_val);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8govrcLy/2/